# State pattern and encapsulation

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, agent, state-pattern

I've recently been developing a Java application and I've been attempting to follow the GoF's state pattern to attempt to tidy up the code.

The program uses a multi-agent system's agents to evaluate instructions on the behalf of a "super agent" (example below).

The super agent can exist in two states, and it's getting messy having if statements everywhere checking the state and then performing state specific behavior.

Here is a (very) simplified version of the program. The actual implementation has alot more state specific behavior.

```
public class superAgent
{
    //the state of the super agent
    private States state;

    //Contains information related to the operation of exampleClass. This should not be exposed through mutator methods.
    private HashMap<String, SpecificInstructionData> instructionData

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ExampleInstruction> exampleQueue

    private final Object instructionLock = new instructionLock

    public enum States
    {
        STATE1,
        STATE2;
    }

    public void setState(state s)
    {
        state = s
    }

    //Called by a thread that continuously takes from the queue 
    private void runningThread()
    {
        while(isRunning)
        {
            synchronized(instructionLock)
            {
                ExampleInstruction ei = exampleQueue.take();
                //Add some data about the instruction into instructionData
                //send the instruction to an available agent
            }
        }
    }

    public void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent()
    {
        if(state == States.STATE1)
        {
            doState1Behavior();
        }
        else if(state == States.STATE2)
        {
            doState2Behavior();
        }
    }

    private void doState1Behavior()
    {
        synchronized(instructionLock)
        {
            //make state specific modifications to instructionData
        }
    }

    private void doState2Behavior()
    {
        synchronized(instructionLock)
        {
            //make state specific modifications to instructionData
        }
    }
}
```

The state pattern would be perfect for encapsulating the behavior of the specific states into different classes according to the GoF pattern (the superAgent class would be the context). However there are two problems, both of which (IMO) break encapsulation:

1. Most state specific behavior needs to make changes to private members (in the above example, instructionData) of the super agent. The members contain data which probably shouldn't be accessible and **definitely** shouldn't be mutable to wrapping classes.
2. The state specific behavior needs to be synchronized with behavior that isn't state specific. Without exposing the lock objects (in the above example instructionLock) by either making it public or using a getter the state and context are unable to share a lock. Exposing the lock violates OOP because it could potentially be used by wrapping/extending classes.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how I could encapsulate this state specific behavior, bearing in mind the example and the two points above?

Comment: 1. You don't need to pass mutable data. A states method could return data the super agent can process. I don't know if that is more beneficial then passing data as an argument. 2. Shared the lock does not violate anything I'm aware of.

Comment: If the lock was to be shared between the context & states, then its level of accessibility would be violate Oracle's secure coding standards.

Ref: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK00-J.+Use+private+final+lock+objects+to+synchronize+classes+that+may+interact+with+untrusted+code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve both problems by using [Double Dispatch](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/download/attachments/220441849/double-dispatch.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1359481987000) between the state instances and the `superAgent` instance to avoid breaking encapsulation.

Say you already implemented the State Pattern. `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent` would look like:

```
public void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent() {
  state.instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent();
}
```

Each `State` implements `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent` using double dispatch this way:

```
abstract class State {
  abstract void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent();
}

class State1 extends State {
  void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent() {
    // instance variable
    agent.instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState1();
  }
}

class State1 extends State {
  void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgent() {
    // instance variable
    agent.instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState2();
  }
}
```

Doing this you let the each `State` specify **what** to do, but is the `superAgent` instance who decides **how** to do it. You have full access to the state and locks without making them public.

Finally, you implement both `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState1` and `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState2` in `superAgent`:

```
public void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState1() {
    //this is doState1Behavior original implementation
    synchronized(instructionLock)
    {
        //make state specific modifications to instructionData
    }
}

public void instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState2() {
    //this is doState1Behavior original implementation
    synchronized(instructionLock)
    {
        //make state specific modifications to instructionData
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that, event though `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState1` and `instructionResponseRecievedFromAgentFromState2` are public methods (so the `State` instances can call them), they're only meant to be used only in the context of the State Pattern.

Comment: Very interesting way of approaching the problem. This solution is certainly a potential solution to the problem.

However, this approach isn't entirely appropriate to my scenario because the "how to do it" methods are still exposed, and they functionality I'm talk about really shouldn't be

I solved the problem ultimately by passing 3 reference variables (including the lock) of the super agent to the state class using the constructor, allowing me to mutate them from within the state without exposing them

I've still used this approach for some state specific behavior. Very useful suggestion

Comment: Hi! Keep in mind that the exposed methods tells "what" has to be done, the "how" is tied to the way you implement them. About your approach: notice that allowing an object to be mutated from outside by exposing the internal state is not a good idea. Besides dealing with repeated code, for example, you cannot ensure the invariant is not broken. Cheers!

Comment: "Notice that allowing an object to be mutated from outside by exposing the internal state is not a good idea"

Why is this? All objects are declared final (not that this matters becayse of Java's value references anyway) but I can't see any reason not to do this, besides it not being entirely obvious to maintaining programmers, however if it's well documentent I can't see a problem.

Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sure! Here the final keyword on instructionLock means it cannot be re-bound, but nothing prevents an external object holding a ref. to it doing synchronized(instructionLock){...} and causing a potential deadlock.

Another example: imagine passing a collection used to keep internal state to the outside: nothing prevents other objects holding that reference adding or removing elements, and so, changing your private state without you noticing it.

Why documenting what may happen if you do something that is not completely right, when you can avoid it by design?

Let me know your thoughts! Cheers!